# Override Bootstrap styles for CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My friend told me about bootstrap to fix my previous issue (still unsolved) for scaling my images to fit the screen // I need a responsive layout.
Oh my 27 inch monitor the website looks clean like so:
[image]

[image]

However, that is, until I decide to zoom in:

[image]

[image]

So basically the website decides to completely cut off the edges of every image I've implemented. Now I heard that bootstrap would be useful in this case however when I implemented it and through the tutorials to install it - after every stepped, it looked like this:

[image]

So basically, my code decides to spaz out. This is a horrible thing as when I hand in the assignment to my teacher, he will be viewing the website on a much smaller screen which means the website will be zoomed in and everything will be cut off or just look really ugly. How do I fix the bootstrap issue? I tried putting the linking code to the bootstrap css file way before the style.css and index.css file, however the error continued to occur. Here is the code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jared's Workshop | Homepage</title>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <header>
    <div class="number2">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navlinks">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">H o m e</a></li>
          <li><a href="gaming.html">G a m i n g</a></li>
          <li><a href="office.html">O f f i c e</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts.html">C o n t a c t s</a></li>
          <li><a href="checkout.html">C h e c k o u t</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="containimage">
        <div class="logo1">

          <img src="./assets/logos/logoreal2.png">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1" data-image-src="./assets/background/back.jpg"></div>

      <div class="text-justify">
        <div class="abovepic">
          <img src="pc.png"/>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <!-- Slideshow container -->
          <div class="slideshow-container">

            <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
            <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
              <a href="gaming.html"/><img src="./assets/banners/easter.png">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
              <a href='#geforce'/><img src="./assets/banners/easter.jpg">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
              <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
              <a href="gaming.html"/><img src="./assets/banners/whiteout.png">
              <div class="text"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
          </div>
          <br>

          <!-- The dots/circles -->

          <div style="text-align:center">
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
          </div>

  <!--
          <script>
          var slideIndex = 1;
          showSlides(slideIndex);

          function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
          }

          function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
          }

          function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
            if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
          }
          </script>
  -->

          <script>
          var slideIndex = 0;
          showSlides();

          function showSlides() {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            slideIndex++;
            if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
          }
          </script>


        </div>





        <div class="pie">

                      <div class="text2">
                        <h1>HOT BUILDS</h1>
                        <p>Recommended builds with hot prices from our <a href="#music.html" class="website" target="_blank"><b>gaming builds.</b></a></p>
                      </div>

                    <section id="tickets">
                      <div id="tickets container">

                        <div class="ticketsbottom">
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/helios2.jpg)">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/helios.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insidehelios.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2>HELIOS</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$3355</b><br>- Intel Core i7 10700K 3.8GHz<br>- 16GB Gigabyte Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- WD 500GB SSD OS Drive<br>- ASUS RTX 3070 8GB Graphics<br>- eVGA 750W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/coal2.png)">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/hot1.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insidecoal.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2>COAL</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$3360</b><br>- Intel Core i7 10700KF 3.8Ghz<br>- 16GB Gigabyte Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- Samsung 500GB SSD OS Drive<br>- Gigabyte RTX 3070 8GB Graphics<br>- Gigabyte 750W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                          <div class="ticketsitem" style="background-image: url(./assets/background/remix2.png">
                            <div class="icon">
                              <img src="./assets/icons/bhov/remix.png"/>
                              <div class="iconinside">
                                <img src="./assets/icons/ahov/insideremix.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <h2>REMIX</h2>
                            <p><b style="font-size: 1.8rem">$6270</b><br>- Intel Core i9 10850K 3.6Ghz<br>- 32GB Corsair Memory<br>- Gigabyte Z490 Motherboard<br>- Samsung 2TB SSD OS Drive<br>- Gigabyte RTX 3090 24GB Graphics<br>- eVGA 1000W Power Supply</p>
                            <a href="#music" type="button" class="superbutton" >Add to cart</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </section>
        </div>
        <div class="between">

          <div id="geforce">
            <div class="glogo">
              <img src="./assets/icons/geforce 3.png"/>
            </div>
            <iframe width="900" height="506.25" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/casgtX_HMTQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
          <!--<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuDX6wNfjqc" type="button" class="superbutton" target="_blank">SEE VIDEO</a> </div>--->


        <div class="img1">
          <div class="frames">
            <hr>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oQH1dP13O3s" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5k7UPag-9x4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T3lopR0XpOE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>

        <p>
          All Rights Reserved. Copyright 1991-2020 PLE Computers Pty Ltd (ABN: 48 051 046 596). The PLE Computer Logo & Mouse Pointer in Circles are registered Trademarks of PLE Computers Pty Ltd. All other trademarks and copyrights are the property of their respective owners. For further information on terms of service & conditions please see Terms & Conditions. Ultrabook, Celeron, Celeron Inside, Core Inside, Intel, Intel Logo, Intel Atom, Intel Atom Inside, Intel Core, Intel Inside, Intel Inside Logo, Intel vPro, Itanium, Itanium Inside, Pentium, Pentium Inside, vPro Inside, Xeon, Xeon Phi, and Xeon Inside are trademarks of Intel Corporation in the U.S. and/or other countries.
          This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google Privacy Policy and Terms of Service apply.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body, body::after, body::before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.container{

  background: #f9f9f9;



}

.parallax {
  padding: 500px;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;

}

.text-justify{
 z-index: 2;
 position: relative;
 background: repeat;
 background-color: #111111;
}

.text-justify p{
  z-index: 7;

  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  color: white;

}

.container .containimage .logo1{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  z-index: +200;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 900px;



}

.container .containimage .logo1 img{
  width: 1920px;

}

.navlinks{

}

.navlinks ul li:hover{

  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 100%;
}

.navlinks ul li{
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 20%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}





body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }


.navlinks li a{
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
.navlinks a{
  color: white;
  z-index: 2000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;

}

.navbar li{
      display:inline;
}

.navbar{

  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}



header {
  background-color: #16161e;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#16161e;
}

li {

}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;

  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  transition: 0.5s;

}

p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

element.style {
}


p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
.text-justify {
    text-align: justify!important;
    margin-top: 0;

}



.text2 h1{
  text-align: block;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: white;

  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  text-align: center;

  font-weight: 300;
}

.text2 p{
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-left: 400px;

  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.text2 {
    background-color: #111111;
    padding: 100px;
    transform: translate(0,-70%);

}



.img1 a img{

  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;

}



.between img{
  padding: 20px;


}

.between{
  text-align: center;

}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;

}

.website:hover{
  color: gold;
  transition: .5s;
}

.website{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.img1{

  text-align: center;
}

.img1 .frames{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;

}

.between a{
  text-decoration: none;

}

.between img{

  position: relative;
  vertical-align: center;
  float: none;

  top: -80px;

}

.between{
  text-align: center;
}

.superbutton{
  opacity: 100;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #294f65;
  background-color: #fba174;
  border: 2px solid #294f65;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  transition: .6s ease background-color;
  z-index: +99;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  transform: translate(0,40%);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.superbutton:hover{
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff8b52;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.super{
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.superbutton:active{
  color: white;
  background-color: #294f65;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}


/* GEFORCE VIDEO */

#geforce{
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(https://plecom.imgix.net/bo-557053-geforce-rtx-outriders-bundle-video-bkgd-2560x770-d.jpg?auto=format);
  padding: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;

}

#geforce .glogo {
  text-align: center;

}

#geforce .glogo img{
  padding: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  top: -190px;
  transform: translate(0,100%);
}


/* GEFORCE VIDEO END*/


@keyframes text_reveal_box{
  50%{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100%{
    width: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes text_reveal{
  100%{
    color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes box{
  100%{
    opacity: 100%;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
@keyframes items_reveal{
  100%{
    flex-basis: 20%;
    opacity: 1;

  }
}
@keyframes title_reveal{
  100%{
    font-size: 4rem;
    opacity: 1;

  }
}

/*Tickets Section*/

.pie {
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
}


#tickets {
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#ticketstop .sectiontitle h1{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 100;

}
.sectiontitle span{
  color: #347f7d;
}

#tickets .sectiontitle{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 100;

}

#tickets .sectiontitle span{
  color: #347f7d;
}

#tickets p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: translate(0,-30%);
}

#tickets .ticketsitem {

  flex-basis: 15%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  background-size: cover;
  margin: 10px 6px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: +1;
  transition: .2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;


}

#tickets .ticketsitem::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #26323c 0%, #485563 100%);
  opacity: .8;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon{
  height: 80px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}



#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%,-70%);
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 100;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon:hover img{
  opacity: 0
}


#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon .iconinside img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%,-70%);
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon .iconinside img:hover{

  opacity: 100;


}


#tickets .ticketsitem h2{
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#tickets .ticketsitem p{
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}



#tickets .ticketsitem:hover{
  position: relative;

  transition: 0.1s;
}

/* END TICKETS Section */

/*above tickets*/
.abovepic{
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0,-35%);
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
/*below tickets*/


* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;


}



/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

}



/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: -500px;
  transform: translate(0,-380%);
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev{
  left: -500px;
  transform: translate(0,-380%);
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  transform: translate(0,-40%);
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

.mySlides{

  transform: translate(-50%,-55%);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.mySlides img{
  width: 200%;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}


.slide{
    background-image: url(./assets/background/back1.png);
    padding:50px;
    padding-top: 115px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: -200px;

}








.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -16px;
}

.col-25 {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
}

.col-50 {
  -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 50%;
}

.col-75 {
  -ms-flex: 75%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 75%;
}

.col-25,
.col-50,
.col-75 {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.container .containimage {

      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;

      box-shadow: inset 0 0 300px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      z-index: +10000;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.icon-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

span.price {
  float: right;
  color: grey;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other (and change the direction - make the "cart" column go on top) */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .col-25 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad. At first glance there are many ways this is far from a responsive layout. Forcing pixel units on padding, width, etc.. isn't responsive. In most cases responsive design uses percentage units. All of Bootstrap's grid classes are percentage-based and work along with media queries at [specific breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/)

Comment: What I was trying to say my entire post was that I had already made a html website, and when I was closed to finishing he suggests bootstrap.. so I tried to implement it AFTER creating more than half my website and I just wanted to know how to work with it when it’s broken everywhere

Comment: Thanks btw  I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I see you did not use any of Bootstrap's grid classes, to make a responsive layout that matches every screen and resize images and content smoothly, here is an example:

in `html`

```
<section class="tickets">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tickets_item col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="./images/image.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tickets_item col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="./images/image.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="tickets_item col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <img src="./images/image.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

to establish a responsive layout using Bootstrap, you need to use bootstrap `.row` class, In Bootstrap, the `.row` class is used mainly to hold columns in it. Bootstrap divides each row into a grid of 12 virtual columns. please read [Bootstrap's Grid system Documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

so inside the `<div class="row"></div>` there is by default a virtual 12 columns, you can can give every `ticket_item` a custom width in small/medium/large/xlarge screens by adding `.col- + screen size + column count`  to be:
`.col-sm-12` gives full width in small screens.
`.col-md-6` gives half width i.e. 6 columns in medium screens.
`.col-lg-4` gives 33.333 % width, i.e. 4/12 columns in large screens.

Comment: So when I add the '<div class="tickets_item col-sm-12 col-md-4">' to my code along with its row div and closing divs, it looks very odd: